# pandas date time disaster, cannot convert rows of dates to anything uniformly usable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given this sample data from an excel file to csv (using Pandas) I have tried every form of pd.datetime to convert these seemingly uniform string dates to datetime format.  Use the flags errors='coerce' I lose a bunch of dates.  No good.  Use errors='ignore' I get some columns with dtype datetime and others remain object.  No good.  The goal is to grab the years for all these dates and then bin them in five year bins from 1980-2000.  At this point I am thinking pandas datetime parser is like the Kardashian of parsers, famous for nothing.

```
Date_1  Date_2    Date_3      Date_4      Date_5    Date_6      
1000    9/1/2019    NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN 
1001    NaN         NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN 
1002    NaN         1/1/2000 NaN          NaN       NaN 
1003    NaN         NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN 
1004    NaN         4/1/2016 NaN          NaN       NaN 
1005    NaN         NaN      NaN          NaN       1/1/2013
```

What have I tried.  pd.todatetime with various flags and without flags.
This is the most common error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2053         try:
-> 2054             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   2055             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
```

Tried even converting all date strings to just strings and using regex to grab just the year.  I only need the year for each of these dates to then use pd.cut or groupby and get the following result in bins.

```
1980 - 1985     347
1986 - 1990     450
1995 - 2000     47
```

and so on.

However, having done what I thought was a good set of operations, I keep ending up with dramatically less in date figures than are in the actual data set, like 50% of the dates just disappear from the dataset no matter what datetime conversion is attempted.  So much frustration that I have actually linked half the [dataset in csv format here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpTLvpi3BAv68bed7JvaQlkMwWqI9Qf4/view?usp=sharing) so you can actually check out what I am dealing with in reality

Comment: Some rows have no dates and some others have more than one, how do you want to deal with them?

Comment: @NathanFurnal I want to ignore entries that are NaN (have no dates) and gather all the dates to then parse the year out and bin the years. Problem is, using pd.datetime some columns convert and others remain object.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the data, or parsing it with pd.to_datetime. Works just fine for me. Besides some ranting about pandas to_datetime, your question doesn't show any code you tried that fails...

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried pd.todatetime.df[i] in a loop for every column. Some remained object dtype while others converted to datetime.  If there is another method that converts all columns to dtype datetime please share that. I can’t use various flags to help as I noted above, huge data loss results.

Comment: Nothing fancy; just loaded your data with `pd.read_csv` and ran `for c in df.columns[1:]: df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])`. This converts *everything* to datetime64 as it should (pandas 1.1.4 on Python 3.8.5 x64 on Windows 10). Don't need to set *any* flags (keywords).

Comment: @MrFuppes I will try that right now.  I have attempted this already, I believe and got a mixed column dtype result.  But, perhaps human error entered into my code.  Nah, not possible.  :)

Comment: Nope, I ran your precise code, (and I think I tried it before) and got the same error and edited my question above to include that error info.  I am on a windows 10 machine using Python 3.8 as well.

Comment: hm... looks like you're using 32 bit Python? which pandas version?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Pandas 3.8.5 32 bit version.  I never noticed that.  Perhaps an upgrade to the 64 bit version is recommended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224736/discussion-between-mrfuppes-and-john-taylor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution which is a bit convoluted but should work.

Read the values, convert to string, remove nan's, gather the dates into a list per row, filter the lists for where there are actual values, explode the lists and you have a series with the dates. You can do it in one go but I'll break down the steps.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("tst_file.csv")
df = df.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
df_str = df.astype(str).replace("nan", "")
df_lists = df_str.apply(list, axis=1)
df_filtered = df_lists.apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y : len(y) >= 1, x)))
clean = df_filtered.explode()

dates = pd.to_datetime(clean, format="%m/%d/%Y")
ts = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=["time"])
ts["year"] = ts["time"].dt.year
```

Now you can bin the years as you wish

It looks like this :

```
          time    year
0   2019-09-01  2019.0
1   2011-01-01  2011.0
2   2000-01-01  2000.0
3          NaT     NaN
4   2016-04-01  2016.0
..         ...     ...
995 2020-01-01  2020.0
996 2015-02-01  2015.0
997 2016-04-01  2016.0
998 2001-12-01  2001.0
999 2016-01-01  2016.0

[1162 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can keep the original index and create a new one, a good way is also to set the dates as index and use `loc` to grab the relevant slices.

```
ts = ts.reset_index()
ts = ts.set_index("time").sort_index()
```

For example, there are 285 rows in this interval

```
ts.loc["2010":"2015"]

            index    year
time                     
2010-01-01    418  2010.0
2010-01-01    318  2010.0
2010-01-01    416  2010.0
2010-01-01    676  2010.0
2010-01-01    729  2010.0
...           ...     ...
2015-12-01    827  2015.0
2015-12-01    409  2015.0
2015-12-01    194  2015.0
2015-12-02    804  2015.0
2015-12-15    513  2015.0

[285 rows x 2 columns]
```